# invoice2 package: Replace VAT with GST

Tags: package-options, invoice2

I'm trying to generate an invoice using the invoice2 package. It works (adding items and applying a VAT at a rate I supply). However, I would like the invoice to show "GST" instead of "VAT". The documentation indicates several options that should do this, but they don't seem to be working for me. For example, neither the directive `\invoiceoptions{invoice2-vat="GST"}` nor `\invoiceoptions{invoice2-vat-total="GST"}` work.

Here's an MWE of what I'm trying to do. Everything works, except I want 'VAT' to say 'GST'.

```
\usepackage{invoice2} % Required to produce an invoice.
\usepackage{translations} 

\begin{document}
    This is my invoice.
    
\invoiceoptions{vat=0.05}
    \begin{invoice}[currency-in-header]
        \invoicesingleitem{40 h at \$50 per hour}{2000}
    \end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have good ideas, but the commands are different. Adding two declarations in the preamble is enough in your example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{invoice2} % Required to produce an invoice.
\usepackage{translations} 

\DeclareTranslationFallback{invoice2-vat}{GST}
\DeclareTranslationFallback{invoice2-vat-total}{GST}
\begin{document}


    This is my invoice.
    
\invoiceoptions{vat=0.05}
    \begin{invoice}[currency-in-header]
        \invoicesingleitem{40 h at \$50 per hour}{2000}
    \end{invoice}
\end{document}
```

[image]